# Creating the IPA File To Upload the Lite Version APP to App Store - XCode 4

Tags: ios4, distribution, ios-provisioning, ipa

I already have an application on App Store. I'm now finishing the LITE version of this application. The way I created the LITE version was to copy the FULL version project and change the relevant features so they match what I want to have in the LITE version. I also changed the Project Name (from "AppName" to "AppName Lite"). I also created in the Provision Portal new App ID, Provision and Distribution Profiles, downloaded the Certificates and dropped them on the XCode icon.

The LITE version runs perfectly on Simulator and on Device. Now I wish to create this **ipa** file so I can upload it via Application Upload. but... I get an error saying: **Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile**

1. If anyone had simliar scenario, please share what you did to solve it.
2. If anyone knows of a good TUTORIAL explaining all the related steps required to upload an App to App Store (and please please please don't share a link directing to Apple Provision Portal, following it caused all the confusion I have now), maybe something that also explains the rational behind their long-weird-unintuitive process.

thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means, you do not have certificate which is referred from your distribution provisioning profile.
You should create new certificates and provisioning profiles. i.e.. 
Create new Certificate Signing Request and proceed with creating certificate for distribution and provisioning profile. This should validate your binary.

Hope this help, please ask if it does not. 
Zain Syed